# Create ansible play that works with forward slashes

Tags: ansible, escaping

I have a use case to use R's devtools::install_github

```
---
- hosts: slurm_w
  vars:
    arg: "USCbiostats/slurmR"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=arg
    - shell: R -e devtools::install_github({{ arg }})
      register: find
    - debug: var=find.stdout.lines
```

What I'd like to do is write plays that can use install_github

I know there is another method: githubinstall("PackageName") which is easier to work with, but ultimately I'd like a solution to work around the forward slash

The only way I can really get this to install as is is to use a bash script that I ultimately call from an ansible play

error

```
fatal: [slurmw01]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "R -e devtools::install_github(\\\"USCbiostats/slurmR\\\")", "delta": "0:00:00.004260", "end": "2020-12-21 21:19:26.638852", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-12-21 21:19:26.634592", "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `R -e devtools::install_github(\\\"USCbiostats/slurmR\\\")'", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('", "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `R -e devtools::install_github(\\\"USCbiostats/slurmR\\\")'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the message clearly says, it's not the forward slashes, it's the open paren which is a [shell metacharacter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-metacharacter)

You need to escape the expression that is provided to `-e` to keep bash from trying to interpret the `(`. The easiest way is via the [`| quote` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings)

```yaml
    - shell: R -e {{ ('devtools::install_github("' ~ arg ~ '")') | quote }}
      register: find
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is occurring because of extra quotes required for the expression (`-e`) passed to the R command.

Typically run like:

```
R -e "devtools::install_github('USCbiostats/slurmR')"
```

We can escape the quotes, like so:

```yaml
- shell: "R -e \"devtools::install_github('{{ arg }}')\""
  register: find
```